# SQL Agent Job to backup database on another instance?

Tags: sql-server

I have all my backup jobs as Agent jobs. I want to backup a database (sharepoint content) that lives on another instance on the same server. How?

Linked Server doesn't work. Can I script it another way? Even SSIS?

SQL 2008 R2

Comment: what did you try in SSIS ? I think there is a backup database task for that.

Comment: Backup database from one instance, disconnect, connect to another instance, restore database?

Comment: Sorry Justin - I want this automated for off-site backup daily

Comment: Unless there is another answer, I have used SSIS with a connection to the sharepoint instance and an 'execute SQL task', then exported the SSIS package and run that package via my local instance sql agent. So everything is neat and tidy!

Comment: if you use sql task in ssis, you can just use agent job with sql query... without using SSIS it would me more tidier

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to handle this would be to create a stored proc that does your backup on the remote instance and call the sproc over the linked server.